# What is the difference between these codes?

Tags: javascript

```
<input type='text' id='txt' name='txtName' size='20' value='testing'/>

<script type="text/javascript" language='javascript'>
  var val = document.getElementsByName('txtName');
  alert(val[0].value);
  alert(window.txtName.value);
</script>
```

In above code we are using

```
alert(val[0].value);

alert(window.txtName.value);
```

these two ways for getting value from object. What is the difference between both ways and which way is best.

Comment: I doubt window.txtName will return something.

Comment: @Phillippe is correct, it'd be `window.txt.value` to get anything here.

Comment: @Philippe: It will on IE. IE conflates the `id` and `name` namespaces, and dumps all of those symbols on `window`.

Comment: On **window** ? I thought these properties lived in the **document** object. Anyway, it's wrong to use it like this IMHO

Comment: @Phillippe - It's IE misbehaving, since a name doesn't have to be unique, e.g. the same element on 4 forms, this is just a bad thing for IE to ever have done.

Comment: @Philippe: Yes, really on `window` (and really `name` s). :-) As Nick says, it's an example of IE getting it very, very wrong. Messes up `getElementById`, too. IE8 doesn't do it when it's not in compatibility mode, they've seen the light.

Comment: BTW, the `language` attribute of `<script>` elements is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
alert(window.txtName.value);
```

This is the Wrong Way, which only works on IE. IE copies all named and IDd elements into properties of `window` and hence also global variables, which causes all sorts of problems. Don't rely on this.

The better way of doing it like that is:

```
alert(document.forms[0].elements.txtName.value);
```

assuming that the `input` was in the first `<form>` on the page. You can also use a form name, if it has one:

```
alert(document.forms.someform.elements.txtName.value);
```

and it's also possible to shorten that:

```
alert(document.someform.txtName.value);
```

although I wouldn't recommend doing so as you stand a greater chance of clashes between names and properties.

This:

```
alert(document.getElementsByName('txtName')[0].value);
```

is OK, but since you already have `id='txt'` on the input it's going to be simpler and faster to use that instead of relying on the non-unique `name` attribute:

```
alert(document.getElementById('txt').value);
```

Comment: @dhali: If this answer suits your needs, please tick the check mark, so we can see this question got answered good enough.

Answer (score 2):

In the first method, you're finding all the elements that have a value of `txtName` for their `name` properties. From the result, you're fetching the first matched item.

In the second method, you rely on the browser to have made the element with the name `txtName` accessible via a shorthand property, `txtName`, on the `window` object.

As you can see, one is superfluous if you know there's always just one element; and the other is problematic if you don't know that there's always just one element. Also, in most browsers, the second method won't even work.

I wouldn't recommend any of those means of accessing an item, but rather access by id - `document.getElementById('txt').value` - when you know there's just one specific element that you want to access.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code find out whole dom  i.e whole html page

```
var val = document.getElementsByName('txtName');
alert(val[0].value);
```

Following might be the error because by the following line it's add textName to the window object.

```
alert(window.txtName.value);
```

chck more about this : http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable

Comment: That's not correct. "window" is the "global variable scope" object when javascript is running in a browser. Any global variable is also a property of the "window" object.